# Creating a slide effect using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been following a project on the Youtube channel Devtips. Everyting was working fine until I tried creating a slide effect using JavaScript. Nothing happens when I click the link to make slide.

CSS:

```
.alt-section{
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #e4e7ec;
}

.section-work{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.work-belt{
    width: 200%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
}

.thumb-wrap, .work-wrap{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
} 

.thumb-container{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.work-container{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

.work-container > img{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.work-return{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -45px;
}

@media (max-width: 740px){
    .work-container{

    }

    .work-return{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #work2{
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}

.work-return:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

.thumb-unit{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/yAzmRg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.thumb-unit2{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/BDUPbm);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit2:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.thumb-unit3{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/dwUDmj);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit3:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.thumb-unit4{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/YQknM6);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit4:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.thumb-unit5{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/7eAsC3);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit5:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.thumb-unit6{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/j6h4iX);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit6:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.thumb-unit7{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/sDYiyH);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit7:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.thumb-unit8{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/PlRIEF);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 16%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb-unit8:hover .thumb-overlay{
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}


.thumb-overlay{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgba(248,23,67,0.5);
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s; /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 0.2s;

    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    });

$(function(){
    workBelt();
});

function workBelt(){
    $('.thumb-unit').click(function(){
        $('.work-belt').css('left','-100%');
    });

    $('.work-return').click(function(){
        $('.work-belt').css('left','0%');
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="alt-section section-work">
<h3 id="work">Work</h3>
<div class="work-belt">

<div class="work-wrap">
<div class="thumb-container">
<div href="" class="thumb-unit">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Chouchou</strong>
</div>
</div>

<div href="" class="thumb-unit2">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Libellule</strong>
</div>
</div>

<div href="" class="thumb-unit3">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Magnifique</strong>
</div>
</div>

<div href="" class="thumb-unit4">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Soirée</strong>
</div>
</div>

<div href="" class="thumb-unit5">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Tournesol</strong>
</div>
</div>

<div href="" class="thumb-unit6">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Coquelicot</strong>
</div>
</div>

<div href="" class="thumb-unit7">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Florilège</strong>
</div>
</div>

<div href="" class="thumb-unit8">
<div class="thumb-overlay">
<strong>Pamplemousse</strong>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="work-wrap">
<div class="work-container">
<div class="work-return"><img src="Img/arrow.png" width="25px" height="25px"></div>
<h3 id="work2">Do work</h3>
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: #CCC;"></div>
<p>Testing text.</p>

<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: #CCC;"></div>
<p>Testing text.</p>

<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: #CCC;"></div>
<p>Testing text.</p></div>
</div>

</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery's [`$.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to do this, as [`$.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) sets the value directly.

```
$('.work-belt').animate({'left': '-100%'}, 1000);
```

### Try it

Comment: You example in jsfiddle works fine to me but I still can't get it to work myself. Could it be something wrong with the way I connect the script with my project?

Comment: @Crocus Have you [included jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)? If you did, open your JS console (F12 key) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: [Transitions](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). Since jquery is already being used.

Answer (score 0):

solution provided by blex is acceptable but I have feeling you wanted to slide element using only css transition. If thats the case your css style lacks important transition that will animate html node:

```
.work-belt{
    width: 200%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.7s linear;
    transition: left 0.7s linear;
}
```

As you can see class "work-belt" now have 2 extra lines in its style definition.

```
  transition: left 0.7s linear;
```

Above line tells browser to animate "left" property of html node. Animation should lasts for 0.7s (700ms) & it should be linear. Line starting with '-webkit-' prefix does the same but its for webkit browsers.

Please take a look at [working example on jsBin playground](http://jsbin.com/sovatojico/1/edit?html,css,js,output).
Added elements: refference to jQuery library + fixed css.

Additionaly plese check rest of your css styles - I am preety sure styles like this one:

```
-webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
```

are not correct. For animation you should use "transition".

Hope that will help you.